# Start a line in bash script with !! (double bang)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How would I start a line in a bash/shell script with a double bang in order for the last input to be run again?

I want to pipe the past output of the last run program into a new program. For example, if I ran `ls -l` last, and now i run this script, I want to pipe `ls -l` into `<some program here>` for manipulation.

```
#! /bin/sh
!! | <some program here>
```

I am getting

> !!: not
>   found

Comment: As far as i know the bangbang executes the last executed command again (in interactive mode). This might not be the right approach - imagine deleting files and then running your command, you would get different output, since you were to try to delete already removed files again. Piping the output of ls to your program can look like this: `ls -l | ./yourscript.sh`. Note that your script needs to be executable.

Comment: History expansion needs to be available (it's not in `/bin/sh`) and enabled (it's not by default in a non-interactive shell).

Comment: thank you guys.  say i wanted to run myscript.sh after running the first command.  Is there no way to access the line from history and run it again in myscript.sh?

Comment: You are probably better off defining a shell function to use instead of writing a script. There is also the issue of making sure that the history of your current shell (which may exist only in memory, not yet written to a file) is read into the history list of your script on start-up.

Comment: Can you not just use `"$@"` in the script and run it as `./script.sh "!!"` ?

Comment: You should use a function instead. Something like: `banana() { eval "$(history -p \!\!)" | YOUR_COMMAND_HERE; }`

Comment: Last two comments worked just as well

Comment: @123: that will break if the command contains quotes. You'd want `./script.sh !!:q` instead, so that the whole thing is passed as a single argument (the `:q` modifier does that).

Comment: for what it's worth, I have `alias p=less` ("p" for "pager"), so I can do `!!|p` which isn't too much typing.

Comment: What do you mean by *last input*? The last thing that some arbitrary user typed? The last thing that you typed somewhere (in some arbitrary window)? You are starting a completely new process, so I don't see what "last" input would mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to execute the command again in the script you can access the `~/.bash_history` file in order to get the history (this can be buggy in case you have multiple terminal windows open!).

If you just want to take the output of a command and pipe it to the shell script containing a program, then your command would look like this:

`<yourcommand> | ./yourscript.sh`

and your script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/a/b/g' <&0
```

where the `<&0` part pipes stdin of the script to the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

The double bang and `bang partial_previous_command` are available in interactive shell. I don't believe you can use it in a script.

But if this was a straight up script you can just reuse the command. In case of a loop, hold that in a $var, then refer to the $var instead of using those interactive items.

Comment: A better design is to save the output to a temporary file, or use a process substitution with `tee` to process it in two different commands.